# Balancing 5v5 teams (skill wise)

Tags: python, math

im trying to write an algorithm that gets a list of tuples with 10 players' names and  MMR ratings (ELO system) and the algorithm will output 2 teams which should be as balanced as possible.

first of all, mathematically, should I balance around AVG MMR or MEDIAN? and If anyone got a more legend approach I would love to hear it.
beside that, I sometimes get this msg (

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    Red,Blue=closest(lst,1591)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\dd.py", line 45, in closest
    lst.remove(Red[1])
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list)
```

what can cause it?

```
import random
import statistics
def avgmmr(lst,num):
    sumi=0
    for i in range(num):
        #print(lst[i][1])
        sumi+=lst[i][1]
    
    return sumi/num


def closest(lst,avg):
    cavg=0
    bestdiff=1000
    Red=[]
    placeholder=[]
    randi=random.randint(0,9)
    newavg=((avg*5)-lst[randi][1])/4 "choosing 1 player random and checking the neeeded avg with him"
    for i in range(1,5)
        for j in range(1+i,8):
            for k in range(j+1,8):
                for s in range(k+1,8):
                    curravg=(lst[i][1]+lst[j][1]+lst[k][1]+lst[s][1])/4  "checking the current avg of 4 players"
                    currdiff=abs(newavg-curravg)
                    if (newavg==curravg) : 
                        Red.append(lst[i],lst[j],lst[k],lst[s])
                        return Red
                    elif(currdiff<bestdiff): "checking if we found the closest to the avg so far"
                        cavg=curravg
                        bestdiff=abs(newavg-cavg)
                        placeholder=[i,j,k,s]
    Red=[lst[randi],lst[placeholder[0]],lst[placeholder[1]],lst[placeholder[2]],lst[placeholder[3]]]
    Red.append(avgmmr(Red,5))
    lst.pop(randi)
    lst.remove(Red[1])
    lst.remove(Red[2])
    lst.remove(Red[3])
    lst.remove(Red[4])
    bavg=avgmmr(lst,5)
    lst.append(bavg)
    return Red,lst
```

Comment: I suggest adding `print()` statements to debug your code. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more debugging tips.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah I have it in my code, left it out for clarity

Comment: You should definitely balance according to the average rather than to the median. Only caring for the median would allow for hugely unbalanced teams. As an extreme example, team1=[999, 999, 1000, 10000, 10000] and team2=[0, 0, 1000, 1001, 1001] both have the same median 1000, but obviously team1 is much much much stronger than team2.

Comment: If you've decided to balance the averages, then this is exactly the so-called [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Answer (score 0):

#### About balancing the median or balancing the mean

- Balancing the medians is a terrible idea. Consider the extreme example eam1=[999, 999, 1000, 10000, 10000] and team2=[0, 0, 1000, 1001, 1001]: both have the same median 1000, but obviously team1 is much much much stronger than team2.
- Balancing the means makes this problem exactly the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

#### Greedy number partionning

I couldn't be bothered to understand and debug your code, but here is an implementation of [greedy number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Approximation_algorithms).

This is a simple greedy algorithm:

- Sort the players by their rating;
- Consider the next two players;
- Add the stronger of these two players to the currently weaker team;
- And the weaker of these two players to the currently stronger team.

Due to its greedy nature, it is not guaranteed to find the optimal solution. However, it is guaranteed to find a 7/6-approximation. That is, the ratio `(average rating of stronger team with this algorithm) / (average rating of stronger team in optimal solution)` is guaranteed to be between 1 and 1.167.

```py
import random

def get_rank(player):
    return player[1]

def make_teams(players):
    sorted_players = sorted(players, key=get_rank)
    team1 = []
    team2 = []
    total_diff = 0
    for p1, p2 in zip(sorted_players[::2], sorted_players[1::2]):
        current_diff = get_rank(p2) - get_rank(p1)
        if total_diff * current_diff >= 0:
            team2.append(p1)
            team1.append(p2)
            total_diff -= current_diff
        else:
            team2.append(p2)
            team1.append(p1)
            total_diff += current_diff
    return team1, team2

players = [(name, random.randint(1200, 2500)) for name in ['Yao', 'Ilshat', 'Juan', 'Hannah', 'Sadaph', 'Anand', 'Khadija', 'Mohammed', 'Donglai', 'Morgan']]

team1, team2 = make_teams(players)

avg1 = sum(r for n,r in team1) / len(team1)
avg2 = sum(r for n,r in team2) / len(team2)
avg = (avg1*len(team1) + avg2*len(team2)) / len(players)

print(players)
print(avg1, team1)
print(avg2, team2)
print('ratio: ', max(avg1, avg2) / avg)

# [('Yao', 1757), ('Ilshat', 2318), ('Juan', 1560), ('Hannah', 1380), ('Sadaph', 2462), ('Anand', 1332), ('Khadija', 1644), ('Mohammed', 1449), ('Donglai', 1531), ('Morgan', 2284)]
# 1738.4 [('Hannah', 1380), ('Mohammed', 1449), ('Khadija', 1644), ('Yao', 1757), ('Sadaph', 2462)]
# 1805.0 [('Anand', 1332), ('Donglai', 1531), ('Juan', 1560), ('Morgan', 2284), ('Ilshat', 2318)]

# ratio:  1.0188
```